# Does sync file reading block all javascript execution or just the event loop its reading in?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

I am using the node module jsonfile to read a json file and route it using the express module and res.json()

To my understanding I cant use the async read because manipulation of the json can only be handled in the callback making it effectively impossible to return the data and serve it using res.json()

```
app.get('/api/announcements', function(req, res) {
    res.json(utils.getAnnouncements())
})

getAnnouncements: function() {
    data = jsonfile.readFile('announcements.json', function(err, obj) {
        //return obj
    })
    //return data
}
```

is what I want but in practice this either returns `undefined` or a `promise` depending on the implementation.

Would reading the file synchronously block the execution of the entire server or just the event loop of the `app.get('/api/announcements')`

Also, what would be the most correct way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire Node process has a single event loop, so reading synchronously would block EVERYTHING. (clustering withstanding...)

You want to do something like:

```
app.get('/api/announcements', function(req, res) {
   //define anonymous function that will be used when getAnnouncements is done.
   utils.getAnnouncements(function(err,fileData){
     // handle if(err)
     res.json(fileData)
   })
})

getAnnouncements: function(callback) {
  //read file async, using callback function to handle results
  jsonfile.readFile('announcements.json', function(err, fileData) {
     callback(err, fileData)
  })
  //or just `jsonfile.readFile('announcements.json',callback)`
}
```